# How can I access my Auth0 token directly in my Entity's context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, auth0

I am currently able to access my Auth0 token in my API by passing it through the controller, down to the service layer, down to my unit of work, down to the entity framework.

I would like to abstract this and pass my token down to entity framework, by just using dependency injection. Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

```
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IService _service;

        public HomeController( IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
         string accessToken = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
         _service.SetToken(accessToken); 
         await _service.Delete(id);
         return Ok();
        }
```

I continue on with this process of passing the token down through a SetToken method on each layer. I am looking for a way to avoid this to make my code more maintainable because I am going to have multiple controllers with multiple methods and it would get tedious to pass this through for every method and controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For accessing `User` in `DbContext`, you could try to resolve the service like below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options
        , IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        string accessToken = httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```